# Renderscript return F64 allocation type, how do you read it in java?

Tags: android, renderscript

I created an allocation using a F64 as the element because I need the 64 bit precision for calculations:

```
Allocation mOutAllocation = Allocation.createSized(mRS,Element.F64(mRS),1,Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

I am trying to get the result back after calling the mScript.forEach_root(mOutAllocation). Normally you would usually copy the mOutAllocation to an array and process the array but double is not one of the available array types (only bytes[], int[], float[], short[], and bitmap).

```
mScript.forEach_root(mOutAllocation);
    double[] x = new double[1];

    mInAllocation.copyTo(x);
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

Can you read it as a long and convert those bits to a double?

Double.longBitsToDouble(long bits) should do the conversion assuming you don't need to byte swap.

It takes a long (64 bits) and interprets that bit pattern as an IEEE double.

EDIT: try this to convert from an int[] to a long

```
int[] ints = new int[]{0x01234567, 0x89abcdef};
long l = (long)ints[0] + ((long)ints[1])<<32;
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(l);
```

Comment: No long in the Allocation.copyTo()...only argument this take are: byte[], int[], float[], short[], and bitmap.

Comment: Wouldn't getting my answer as an int[] or long get rid of the decimal place (which is where I need the precision from double)?

Comment: Unfortunately I think the way renderscript works that will happen.  I was thinking you could lie to the system and copy the bitpattern of a double into a long or 2 ints to pass back, but after further reading I'm not sure you can pull out both more than 32 bits per compute tile (sorry can't remember what rs calls them).  If you can do that then just creatively cast a double* to an int* (ie an int array of 2 elements) and pass them both back.  Then you can use the above java to convert from that "packed" form back to a 64bit double.  If you just cast a double to an int you'll lose precision.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to copy one `double` to and from the RenderScript
context, you can declare a non-static variable and use the 
automatically generated getters/setters:

```
// whatever.rs
double hopper;
void root(const double *in, //...
```

```
// Whatever.java
mScript = new ScriptC_whatever(mRS);
double hopper = 1.234;
mScript.set_hopper(hopper);
```

If you need a full Allocation, you can use NIO to encode your array of
doubles as an array of bytes. Then you can just copy them to an Allocation 
using [`copyFromUncheced`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#copyFromUnchecked%28byte%5b%5d%29).
I don't know how to query byte order in the RenderScript context programmatically-
I discovered that mine needed reversal by trial and error.

```
// whatever.rs
double *target;
void root(const double *in, //...
```

```
// Whatever.java
public void copyDoublesTo(double[] entries, Allocation target) 
    throws IOException {

    if (!target.getType().getElement().isCompatible(Element.F64(mRS))) 
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Type mismatch: Element != F64");
    if (target.getType().getCount() != entries.length) 
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Type mismatch: wrong # of entries");

    mScript.bind_target(target);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(Double.SIZE * dim);
    DataOutputStream longs = new DataOutputStream(bytes);
    long temp;
    for(int i=0; i!=dim; ++i) {
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(entries[i]);

        // reverse byte order:
        temp = Long.reverseBytes(temp);

        longs.writeLong(temp);
    }

    target.copyFromUnchecked(bytes.toByteArray());
}
```

You can also initialize your `Allocation` by binding it to a
pointer then looping through your array of `double`, setting
each entry:

```
// whatever.rs
double *target;
void setTargetEntry(int index, double entry) {
    target[index] = entry;
}
void root(const double *in, //...
```

```
public void copyDoublesTo(double[] entries, Allocation target) {
    if (!target.getType().getElement().isCompatible(Element.F64(mRS))) {
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Type mismatch: Element != F64");
    }
    if (target.getType().getCount() != entries.length) {
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Type mismatch: wrong # of entries");
    }
    mScript.bind_target(target);
    for(int i=0; i!=entries.length; ++i) {
        mScript.invoke_setTargetEntry(i, entries[i]);
    }
}
```

If you need `double2` or similar, just exchange `double` with [`Double2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Double2.html)
in Java. This solves your problem a bit more naturally than the other 
solutions which rely on  ... creative packing schemes, so RenderScript will
figure out pesky issues like byte order for you. However, it entails 
a serial loop over the Allocation, which is *slow*
(and you'll need another to get the data back). For comparison, when I
tested this copying 2^10 `float` averaged 30ms, whereas the native 
`copyTo` method took just 0.1ms. (The NIO method takes around 2ms)